# How to fix resizing of main window by child window in wpf custom control library?

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

There is a program on Delphi. It calls the dll on wpf (custom control library). At the time of creating a wpf window in dll, the size of the main window from main application on Delphi becomes smaller. After the wpf window is closed, the main window remains small. The wpf window is simplest window without controls. I use scale 150% in windows settings. How to fix it?

Comment: Do you have access to the wpf project (sourcecode)?

Comment: Yes, I can modify wpf custom control library